# Exchanging ApplicationCookie to OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType accessToken in AspNet Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

I have a WebApi in the same application as the client and the user is already authenticated because the cookie is present but the javascript have lost its access token.

Is there any way I can request a new access token from the oauth server given the user is authenticated already.

Right now (using parts from the SPA template) the user get directed to the login page by the javascript because it didnt have the access token. I am just wondering instead of asking the user to navigate to social login page to get a externalBearer token to exchange to the access token, if I can get a token from the oauth server given the user is already logged in (the application cookie is present and cookie middleware is in active mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 supports a custom grant type, which allows for some other credential type to be presented. Perhaps you could pervert this extensibility point to use the cookie for this alternative credential. You'd want to beware of and prevent XSRF, though (which is why we want to avoid cookies in the first place for apis). Look into the GrantCustomExtension API on the provider.